# What is the meaning of "in favour of" in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I am confused the meaning of the sentence "He abdicated the throne in favour of his son."

Does it mean "for his son" or "with the help of his son" or something else?

Comment: It simply means that his son succeeded him as king, as he would have done if the father had died.

Answer (score 4):

Here "in favour of" means "to be replaced by".

It's unclear whether the father actually did his son a *favour* by stepping down. All we know is that he resigned and his son assumed (or was to assume) his position.

Answer (score 1):

"in favour of his son" is giving "favour" to his son.

"He abdicated the throne in favour of his son" can be read as "He abdicated the throne for the benefit of his son"

Comment: The literal meaning of **in favour of** is misleading in this context. Whether the son benefited by ascending the throne is open to debate.

Comment: @RonaldSole - I could give up a place on the gallows in favour of someone else, and in fact, I certainly would.